# Display result of algorithm in a label after receiving user input from textField

Tags: swift, xcode8, swift2

Here's my code:

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func Enter(sender: UIButton)
{
    var quantifiedMonth = 0
    let sleepMonth = String(EditCalendarTextBox.text)
    if sleepMonth == "December"
    {
        quantifiedMonth = 12
    }

    EditCalendarLabel.text = String(quantifiedMonth)

}
```

In my app there's a textBox. The user inputs the name of a month. Then I create an integer variable that corresponds with the number of the month, in this case, December, the 12th month. Then I want the Label to display that number, 12, but for some reason the "if" statement gets skipped, and the label displays a '0' as if there was no manipulation of the user input. Thank you for your help. 
[image: Screenshot of my phone with label displaying '0' instead of '12']

Comment: You need to learn about "scope". You can't use a variable outside of its scope.

Comment: Another friendly tip: you're using a mixture of capitalization in your function and variable names. They should be camel case and start with lowercase letters (e.g. func enter(sender: UIButton), let sleepMonth = String(editCalendarTextBox.text)) Take a look at this: https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-style-guide/blob/master/README.markdown

Answer (score 0):

You create `quantifiedMonthString` in the [scope](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of the body of your `if` statement, then leave that scope (the close curly brace), then try to use it after it's gone.

```
if someCondition {
    let x = 1
}
let xCopy = x
```

In the example above, `x` is an integer equal to 1 inside the `if` condition's body. After the closing brace, `x` no longer exists because we've left its scope so the next line is an error (because the symbol `x` is unknown in *this outer scope*).

Comment: Thank you for your help! I did what you said                                            
       ' let x = quantifiedMonthString EditCalendarLabel.text = x ' but I'm still getting the same error

Comment: Ah, well the example I gave wasn't replacement code, it was a simplified way to explain scope and the nature of your error. Read up on scope - I linked a Wikipedia article in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for the article. I read it. I'm pretty sure I understand scope, however I'm still new to programming. I looked at other code I've written with if statements and loops and such, and I still don't understand what the problem is. I updated the code in this post, so maybe you wouldn't mind taking a look at what I've done and point me in the right direction?

Comment: It was a dumb mistake. See below. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Sure. Just FYI, the text you get from the field is already a `String`, no need to create a new `String(withTheField.text)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my fix:

```
//MARK: Actions
@IBAction func Enter(sender: UIButton)
{

    var quantifiedMonth = 0
    if EditCalendarTextBox.text == "December"
    {
        quantifiedMonth = 12
    }

    EditCalendarLabel.text = String(quantifiedMonth)
```